# Remove a cloned element with JQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm cloning a tr and setting it's data-id attribute. I'm then using that data-id to be able to open a modal and if the user clicks the Delete Button use an AJAX call to delete the row. I'm able to pass the data-id and successfully submit the AJAX and delete the item but on success when I try to do a remove on the row it doesn't work.

```
var clone = $('#sizeValueTemplate').clone(true);
clone.data('id', data.id);
clone.removeAttr('id');
clone.show().appendTo('#sizeValueTable');
```

A confirmation modal is shown and upon OK I delete the item. And then on Success:

```
$('tr[data-id='+id+']').remove();
$('#modalDeleteSizeValue').modal('hide');
```

Everything works with no errors except the tr is not removed. The process works for elements present on the page load.

Comment: Please provide jsfiddle :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `data` function does not add `data-` style attributes to the element, which is why you can't look it up. You could try `clone.attr('data-id', data.id);` instead.

Comment: It set's a property on the object in memory representing the element, but it doesn't add an attribute to the element. That's why you can access the value with `this.data("id");` but can't look up the element by the attribute `data-id`.

Comment: You can see this by using firebug to inspect the element

Comment: Perfect. I was using firebug but was confused when I could access it but not remove it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Setting a data using `.data(key, value)` will NOT insert it in the DOM. You need to use `.attr('data-...', value)` for it.

So, this would work:

```
clone.attr('data-id', data.id);
```